# How to compare two primitive integer types stored in an array list?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, bubble-sort

Trying to take input from user. User is not able to calculate the length of input.So I am using ArrayList to add the input from scanner. After that I am conventionally trying to compare the contents of the ArrayList which is primitive integers. Using the get(int index) returns an error :

```
package BubbleSort;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BubbleSort {

    public static ArrayList swap(ArrayList x, int i, int j) {
        Collections.swap(x, i, j);
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List a = new ArrayList();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        a.add(sc.nextInt());

        int x = a.size() - 1;
        boolean unsorted = true;
        while (unsorted) {
            unsorted = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

                if (a.get(i) > a.get(i + 1)) {  //  <===== Error
                    BubbleSort.swap(a, i, i + 1);
                    unsorted = true;
                }

            }
            x--; // Space utilization
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

    }

}
```

Error:

```
The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object
```

How can I compare the integers as we would in arrays?

Comment: You can't use relational operators (like `>`) for Objects.

Comment: I didn’t realize it returns object only I discovered this error.

Answer (score 1):

`List` and `Arraylist` are generic types. Since you didn't define what their type is, they return an object. If you define the type as Integer, then it will return an `Integer` instead of an object. Try defining what their type is by writing

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can read more about generics here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You should try this out:

```
public static ArrayList swap(ArrayList<Integer> x, int i, int j) {
    Collections.swap(x, i, j);
    return x;
}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    a.add(sc.nextInt());

    int x = a.size() - 1;
    boolean unsorted = true;
    while (unsorted) {
        unsorted = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

            if (a.get(i) > a.get(i + 1)) {  //  <===== Error
                BubbleSort.swap(a, i, i + 1);
                unsorted = true;
            }

        }
        x--; // Space utilization
    }
    System.out.println(a.toString());
}
```

1. You used `>` operator with two Objects i.e. `a.get(i)` and `a.get(i + 1)`. In Java you can use this operator only with numeric data types. By using the generics `<Integer>`, you *basically* specify that every element is an integer type.
2. There is no method in `Arrays` class called `toString(List)`. You **can**, however, use the `toString()` method of all objects, like `a.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `a.get(i)` it will return the object Element not a integer value so that's why you can't compare objects like > or < for that you need to cast the object value into `int` then you can compare.

Change your statement like below,

```
if ((int) a.get(i) > (int) a.get(i + 1)) {
```